# Increased file size when preserving ICC color profile in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, color-profile, color-management

I am using PIL to resize images. To make sure the resized image has still the same colors as the original, the ICC color profile gets added to the output image again.

The code looks like the following:

```
image = Image.open('input.jpg')
icc_profile = image.info.get('icc_profile')
# resize the image
resized_image.save('output.jpg', format='JPEG', icc_profile=icc_profile)
```

And everything works fine except that the file size of the resized (smaller) image is even larger than the original.

Example:

- original image => 1.2 MB
- resized image without ICC profile => 485.1 kB
- resized image with ICC profile => 1.8 MB

Here I have uploaded the images if you want to inspect them: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/ueKjdYLKZS/

Does anyone know why the file size increases that much and if there is a workaround?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tried with nearest neighbor (the default) `image.resize((800, 533))` and anti-aliasing `image.resize((800, 533), Image.ANTIALIAS)`. However the resulting file size was 751KB and 747KB, including the icc profile, which is far less than the original picture.

However it is possible that a JPEG becomes larger in file size after it was modified and saved again, when you saved the JPEG with a higher quality (less compression) as when it was initially saved. Or when formerly saving and compressing it added artifacts, that make further compression less efficient.

Comment: Hello Sebastian, thank you for your help. Please could you upload the images somewhere so I can inspect them? Thx!

Comment: @PascalBeyeler https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0qI8KcRpRw4T0loWl9Ma2hGUXM/edit?usp=sharing